# Restricting Calendar View to current week onwards

Tags: wordpress, fullcalendar

I am using the fullcalendar plug in for wordpress by Adam Shaw, I ma using it for a clinet who is making bookings for a gym on a weekly basis.

I was wondering if it is possible to not allow people to select any previous weeks that have past.

Allow people to only select two weeks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if your question is related to this feature request?
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=158

that restricts the date ranges that can be navigated, but if you need to limit what can be "selected" (as in the new [selection features](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/selection/)) you'd have to open a feature request on the issue tracker

Comment: What I was wanting was a rolling view that could be parameterised i.e. set to two weeks and the you can only view in the calendar two full weeks from today. Then tomorrow on view two weeks from tomorrow